# ExpandableListView with RadioButtons.  Select Value For One RadioGroup, Several More Get Selected When Group Expands

Tags: android, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I am replicating an inspection form for a piece of equipment in an android app.  There is an ExpandableListView where group data consists of the different systems of the machine and child data contains the checklist of items with a RadioGroup for the technician to indicate the pass/fail status of the item. All works great except when selecting a value for a RadioButton in one child, it selects a value for the same RadioButton in other groups. So if I had:

```
Group 1
  Question 1
    Passed
    Failed
    Corrected
    NA
  Question 2
    Passed
    Failed
    Corrected
    NA
Group 2
  Question 1
    Passed
    Failed
    Corrected
    NA
  Question 2
    Passed
    Failed
    Corrected
    NA
```

If I select Passed in both questions in Group 1, without ever having gone into group 2, when expanded, 1 or both of the RadioGroups there will have Passed selected also.

The layout I am using to create the child group with the RadioGroup looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dip">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/questionText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<RadioGroup
android:tag="actionGroup"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RadioButton
  android:tag="passed"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Passed"/>
<RadioButton
  android:tag="failed"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Failed"/>
<RadioButton
  android:tag="corrected"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Corrected"/>
<RadioButton
  android:tag="na"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="NA"/>
</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Instantiation of BaseExpandableListAdapter

```
ExpandableListView inspectionQuestions = (ExpandableListView) FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.List);
inspectionQuestions.SetAdapter(new ExpAdapter(this));
```

BaseExpandableListAdapter

```
public class ExpAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private readonly Context context;
    Questions questions = new Questions();
    private int seed = 1000;

    public ExpAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }

    public override Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.inspection_row_2, null);
        }

        int currentID;

        TextView question = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.questionText);
        RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup) convertView.FindViewWithTag("actionGroup");
        radio.Id = seed++;
        RadioButton pass = (RadioButton) convertView.FindViewWithTag("passed");
        pass.Id = seed++;
        RadioButton fail = (RadioButton) convertView.FindViewWithTag("failed");
        fail.Id = seed++;
        RadioButton correct = (RadioButton)convertView.FindViewWithTag("corrected");
        correct.Id = seed++;
        RadioButton na = (RadioButton)convertView.FindViewWithTag("na");
        na.Id = seed++;

        string[][] items = questions.childItems();
        question.Text = items[groupPosition][childPosition];

        return convertView;
    }

    public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return questions.childItems()[groupPosition].Length;
    }

    public override Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1, null);
        }

        TextView groupName = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);

        QuestionGrouper grouper = new QuestionGrouper();
        groupName.Text = grouper.groupItems()[groupPosition];

        return convertView;
    }

    public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override int GroupCount
    {
        get { return 9; }
    }

    public override bool HasStableIds
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

EDITED GetChildView per Suggestion:

```
   public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.inspection_row_2, null);
        }

        TextView question = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.questionText);

        RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.activityGroup);
        int count = radio.ChildCount;

        if (count == 4)
        {
            return convertView;
        }

        RadioButton pass = new RadioButton(context) {Text = "Passed"};
        RadioButton fail = new RadioButton(context) {Text = "Failed"};
        RadioButton correct = new RadioButton(context) {Text = "Corrected"};
        RadioButton na = new RadioButton(context) {Text = "NA"};

        radio.AddView(pass);
        radio.AddView(fail);
        radio.AddView(correct);
        radio.AddView(na); 

        string[][] items = questions.childItems();
        question.Text = items[groupPosition][childPosition];

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: you solve this issue?? if yes how please ?!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the @+id you're using for each RadioButton differs for each group? That's the first thing that comes to mind. Even if they're in a different RadioGroup I'm pretty sure they need to have unique ids so you can do findViewById correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that since I am just assigning the above layout as the layout for group 2 in my ExpandableListAdapter. How would I assign a new ID to each of the RadioButtons?

Comment: I haven't worked much with SimpleExpandableListAdapter. So I'm not too positive. Can you post the rest of your layout xml? I don't really see how what you have up there translates to the 2 questions per group.

Comment: That is the entire layout. SimpleExpandableListAdapters take your grouping data and apply the first layout you provide (i.e. Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1) and then the child data grouping and apply the 2nd layout you provide which is the layout I included above.

Comment: Went back and re-did everything with a BaseExpandableListAdapter like in [this example] (http://android-adda.blogspot.com/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html) and then set the ID of each RadioButton in the GetChildView method using a Randomizer.  So apparently the issue is not with the RadioButtons not having unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You surely should't add Child radio group from xml.. try adding it at run time... then just keep all

those children in a Some key value pair (Child position as key and RadioButton Object).. Now you don't

need uniqueness since You have reference to all RadioButtons.. I had same issue and I did this, now it

works great.. it becomes easy for handling these since you always get childPosition in

**ExpandibleListView** thus making it easy to access..

Comment: Can you maybe provide some code?  When I add RadioButtons in GetChildView rather than xml I get a bunch of RadioButtons under each question rather than the 4 I'm adding.

Comment: Please see edited GetChildView above.  Still having the same issue.

Comment: how to make that ??! @jmease did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Use ListView and Inflate view for each items.
See this link : [RadioGroup in ListView](http://android-designing.blogspot.com/2017/05/radiogroup-in-listview.html)